# how to write short code in word press

Tags: shortcode

I am new in WordPress, I want to write short code with parameters in function. That is in

```
add_shortcode('short code name','function name','parameter1,parameter2');
```

In `add_shortcode()`, I want to pass parameters and this must get in function used for creating short code. Here is the function

```
function function name('parameter1','parameter2') {

}
```

how is it possible?

Comment: I fail to see how this question is off topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), "a minimal example of the PHP code required to create shortcode with attributes" is

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

You can find more detailed information on creating shortcodes in the above referenced documentation.

Comment: i want to create short code dynamically with dynamic short code name and dynamic parameters.is it possible with the given code

Answer (score 0):

Like Keoki said, you can use the above the function and codex docs to help you.  It is really just a matter of applying some programming skills to the concept.

For example, create a database table that holds the shortcode parameters, (shortcode name, parameter1, parameter2, etc.).

Then when the frontend is initialized, add your shortcodes dynamically.

Here is a rough concept:

```
add_action('init', 'dynamic_shortcodes');

    function dynamic_shortcodes() {
        global $wpdb;

        if(!is_admin()) {
            $sql = "SELECT shortcode_name, parameter1, parameter2 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}your_table_name";

            $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

            if($result) {
                foreach($result as $shortcode) {
                    add_shortcode($result->shortcode_name, 'my_dynamic_function');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The harder part is going to be writing the function for my_dynamic_function.  Depending on what you want your shortcodes to do, the above code could help or maybe not.  If it is completely dynamic functionality, then maybe not.